# How many skill points will I have at level 20?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

I'm trying to work out what to spend my points on for my multiplayer character. How many skill points will I have in multiplayer at level 20?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will have 84 skill points at level 20 of Mass Effect 3, if none are spent already.

**Sources:**

1. http://www.gamerswithjobs.com/node/111356
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_Effect_3
3. Personal experience- I own the game and play the multiplayer frequently.

Comment: Incidentally 84 points is enough to fully upgrade 4 abilities as long as no points are spent on the fifth.

Comment: Alternatively, you can fully upgrade 3 abilities, and then get one ability to four ranks and the last to three.

Answer (score 5):

At level 1 you have only 1 skill point, at level 12 you have 40 skill points, at level 16 you have 60 skill points and at level 20 you have indeed 84 skill points.

Possible distributions for the 84 points for your 5 skills are: 6-6-6-6-0 or 6-6-6-5-3 or 6-6-6-4-4 (1 point unused) or 6-6-5-5-4 (2 points unused) or 6-5-5-5-5 (3 points unused). Points unused does not necessarily mean that that character build is inefficient. Depending on your race and character class and your play style, it can be a very good skill distribution.

- You will receive 3 points per upgrade for level 2-6.
- You will receive 4 points per upgrade for level 7-12.
- You will receive 5 points per upgrade for level 13-16.
- You will receive 6 points per upgrade for level 17-20.

There is also a website containing a good online calculator to simulate different skill upgrades for most character classes (no resurgence characters so far unfortunately).